# UITextView vs UILabel: With respect to line-spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

So I have a `UIView` subview with a `UILabel` at the top, static text and minimum scale (To deal with 4" vs 6 twins).

Under that, I have three lines of text with a static string.

Under that, I have a button with custom border, corner radius.

I had an issue with size and spacing. With a 4" screen, I want the line spacing to be 0 so that the `UILabel` and `UIButton` will have the same spacing between top and bottom of the view.

With 6/6+ screen, I want the line spacing to be 1.5~2.0:

With a `UITextView`, I disable user interaction and scrolling, I set the font properties in IB and in my `ViewController`, I override `layoutManager/lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex` with a conditional operator for `:UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` and mainScreen bounds to check height of the screen and return a float based on 4"/4.7"/5.5" screen sizes.

It works great, looks great, has no interaction problems.

But my coworker is insistent that I should be using `UILabel` with line count, because it's static text and shame on me for using a `UITextView`.

Is there a programmatic SYSTEMATIC reason I should be using a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView`? And NO, I'm not looking for the canned copy/pasted "`UILabel` is for static text and `UITextView` is for text you wish to edit blah blah". I want to know the actual fundamental differences when a TextView has its user interaction properties disabled for the purpose of overriding the line spacing.

Comment: "With a 4" screen, I want the line spacing to be 0 so that the UILabel and UIButton will have the same spacing between top and bottom of the view." This sounds totally wrong... Just resize your buttons and set 10px margins between it and the view. Your approach will work wrong as soon as iOS font will change, eg in iOS 9 - end of Helvetica. Whole conception will fail. The code will be also harder to maintain. I think your approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Non editable text can be displayed in UILabel where as if you want to edit text like user input/ scrolling feature you can use textview.

If you want the user to select  the text displayed on UI; you can go for textview. uilabel doesn't support selecting and copy.

UIlabel is derived from UIview but uitextview is derived from UIScrollView. so it inherit the properties of scrollview as well. uitextview conforms to protocol for keyboard handlings

Answer (score 1):

There is no shame for using UITextview instead of UIlabel.

UILabel : You can use it for static text if there is no action in it.

Example : Clickable links inside the static Text.

Disabling the Edit functionality in Textview only disables the Edit. It is not removing the user interaction. So if you have any links or hashtags inside the static text it will Automatically detects.

Like --> #iphone @Ram http://google.com

UILabel will not detect these things.

previously many people subclassing UILabel for deriving this functionality. UITextView has this Functionality inbuilt.

So if you have any clickable components inside the static text use UITextview. Otherwise use UILabel only.